# Speed of compound wound dc motor

Tags: motor, homework, speed

**This is homework.**
Given a 500W, 200V compound wound motor with constant shunt field and a series field that varies with armature current, how do we calculate the change in motor speed.

I know the equation for motor speed \$n\$

$$n \propto \frac{E}{\Phi} $$

therefore

$$\frac{n_{2}}{n_{1}} = \frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}\frac{\Phi_{1}}{\Phi_{2}} $$

where the indices 1, 2 refer to the values in the initial and final states respectively. Here \$E\$ is induced emf and \$\Phi\$ is the net flux.
Given the original speed \$n_{1}\$, the two armature currents \$I_{a, 1}\$ and \$I_{a, 2}\$ and the resistance values of the armature windings \$R_{a}\$ and series coils \$R_{series}\$, I can work out the induced emf with the motor equation
$$E = V_{t} - I_{a}(R_{a} + R_{series})$$
where \$V_{t}\$ is the terminal voltage of 200V.

But I cannot lose the unknown flux \$\Phi\$. Assuming cumulative compound \$\Phi = \Phi_{shunt} + \Phi_{series}\$ and

$$\Phi_{2} = \Phi_{1} + \Delta\Phi
= \Phi_{shunt, 1} + \Phi_{series, 1} + \Delta\Phi_{series}
$$
If we are told that \$I_{a, 2} = 2I_{a, 1}\$, then \$\Delta\Phi_{series} = \Phi_{series, 1}\$
and
$$\frac{n_{2}}{n_{1}} = \frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}\frac{\Phi_{shunt, 1} + \Phi_{series, 1}}{\Phi_{shunt, 1} + 2\Phi_{series, 1}} $$

Without knowing the fluxes, how do we can solve this?

**EDIT: possible solution**

$$\frac{n_{2}}{n_{1}} = \frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}\frac{\Phi_{1}}{\Phi_{2}} = \frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}\frac{I_{1}}{I_{2}} = \frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}\frac{I_{1}}{I_{1} + \Delta I} $$

My assumption is that the net flux will remain proportional to the line current, even though the shunt flux is constant.

Comment: Considering it was homework, you must have found an answer after the due date. You can present it here as an answer to your own question and get credit.

Answer (score 1):

as you said total flux is sum of series flux and shunt flux, whereas the shunt flux is constant in a compound wound motor. the shunt field flux remains constant as If(field current) depends only on Vt which is fixed.so total flux change depends on series flux which is directly proportional to the armature current.
Series Flux = Ks * Armature Current

where Ks is a constant related to the motor's design and magnetic characteristics.
so we have:

n2/n1=(E2/E1)(Ia1/Ia2)